# How do you find the minima of a function in python?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, gradient-descent, function

Say we have a quadratic function in x, where the domain of input x is Real Numbers. How can we find the minimum value of the function (output y) in a programming language like python?

Immediately what strikes me is to use gradient descent but then again how do I calculate the derivatives for any given function? (say sin(x), log (x), etc.) I need a solution from scratch in any programming language.

Using loops is clearly not feasible because the input x can be any real number. It is not possible to check the output value (y) of the function for every possible value of input (x).

I encountered this question in an interview where he went on to say I am free to do it in SQL as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of numerical optimization libraries for most of the programming languages. In python you can use [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).

**Example**:

```py
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.optimize import minimize

    fun = lambda x: np.sin(x)
    x0 = [1.]
    res = minimize(fun, x0)
    print(res.x, fun(res.x))
```

Comment: If you aren't interested in implementing the method yourself, then this is the answer. It's worth noting that you can also specify which algorithm you'd like to use within the options of minimize (and other similar functions).